# Set Boolean Field in Data Browser Parse Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, boolean

How to set boolean field in data browser parse using android?
I used put command which doesn't work. In put command only string field is the input and the object value hence it doesn't work for boolean field.

Query

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(username);
                        query.whereEqualTo("userName", update_user);
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Log.d("result","success");
                                    objects.get(0).put("fullPermission", true);
                                    objects.get(0).saveInBackground();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: What do you mean Data Browser ?? Do you want to set a boolean value in a Class using Android ??

Answer (score -1):

You can easily set a boolean field in your calss using the `put` method:

```
ParseObject yourClass = new ParseObject("YouClassName");
yourClass.put("yourBooleanFieldName", false); // set boolean to false
yourClass.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Thanks Mo Nazemi for your answer. This is working but when i tried in query it doesn't work. Please check my edited question.

Comment: Are you sure the returned object list is not empty ? I mean do you get any exceptions ?